# Speed test для сайта

Tags: javascript, html

Задался идеей сделать спидометр для своего сайта. Перерывал возможные варианты. API не интересно, ибо платно.

Сам функционал - нажимаем на кнопку, проверяется есть либо видеоустройство(вебка) и микрофон , далее производится замер скорости скачки/загрузки.

Может быть есть у кого исходники для разбора? питон и прочее не подходит. Необходим HTML/js , т.к. это дело будет встраиваться в wordpress.

Да, я знаю про гитхаб. Там ничего путного нет.
Да, я гуглил. Нашел только платные апи и 100 лет как не рабочие исходники.
Да, я знаю что необходимо генерировать файл и скачивать, загружать его , но как это реализовать я не знаю.

Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо!

Comment: Непонятно зачем вебка, микрофон и загрузки... https://github.com/librespeed/speedtest

Comment: @InDevX Вебка и микрофон для того, чтобы проверить кандидата. Для работы необходимо: стабильный интернет, вебка и микрофон. Очень много пытаются обмануть , и надо это исключать. ни html ни js толком не знаю. А сделать надо. Как то так и живем:)

Comment: Тогда вам прямая дорога на фриланс. Тут вряд ли кто будет подобным заниматься

Comment: @InDevX Печально, но все равно спасибо:)